# When to add the fadeIn method during this dom manipulation using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I am referencing a particular ID and then I want to add a message AND use fadeIn to change the color of the background to yellow.

So far I have:

```
$("#myID").empty().append("<p>Please login</p>").fadeIn("slow");
```

So would I now be using the CSS method to change the color of the background, fadeIn, then fadeOut to white again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want "Please Login" to fade in.

You need to do this.

```
var login = $("<p>Please login</p>").hide();
$("#myID").empty().append(login).fadeIn();
```

You need to first set the "Please login" as hidden before you can fadeIn.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [.animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) function.  Something like:

```
$("#myID").empty().append(login).animate({background-color: '#123456'}, function() {
   setTimeout(function() { $("#myID").fadeOut('slow'); }, 1500);
});
```

(( air coded - sorry if it doesn't work ))